# Android + Swap custom fonts via styles

Tags: android

I have two styles, each declaring a custom font (Normal and Bold).

```
        <style name="label" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
            <item name="typeface">@string/custom_font_regular</item>
        </style>

        <style name="label.bold">
            <item name="typeface">@string/custom_font_semibold</item>
        </style>
```

In my xml, I set the custom `TextView` to use the "label" style, styling the font to `normal` by default. However, after a user action, I want to swap the `normal font` for the `bold`version via the style `label.bold`.  Is this possible?  Keep in mind, I'm trying to avoid calling `setTypeface()`, which does not take a style as an argument but a pointer to the `bold tff` which seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Take a look at my custom textview as an example:

```
package com.example.ui.components;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.core.ui.R;

public class StandardTextView extends TextView {

    public StandardTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public StandardTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public StandardTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setTypeFaceFromAttributes(attrs.getStyleAttribute());
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextAppearance(Context context, int resid) {
        super.setTextAppearance(context, resid);

        setTypeFaceFromAttributes(resid);
    }

    private void setTypeFaceFromAttributes(int attributeSet) {
        if (attributeSet == -1) {
            return;
        }

        TypedArray a = null;

        try {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.StandardTextView);

            if (a.getString(R.styleable.StandardTextView_typeface) == null) {
                return;
            }

            String typeFaceString = a.getString(R.styleable.StandardTextView_typeface);

            setupTypeface(typeFaceString);

        } finally {
            if (a != null) {

                a.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupTypeface(String typeFace) {
        if (typeFace == null || "".equals(typeFace)) {
            return;
        }

        Resources resources = getResources();
        if (resources == null) {
            return;
        }

        AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();
        if (assetManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, typeFace);

        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

**This is how you might use it:**

```
standardTextView.setTextAppearance(ExampleFragment.this.getActivity(), R.style.label_bold);
```

**Attrs:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="StandardTextView">
        <attr name="typeface" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/default_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.ui.components.StandardTextView
        android:id="@+id/sure_swipe_create_text"
        style="@style/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/example" />
</RelativeLayout>
```